# executing toString() in Eval () - Groovy (method call in Gstring)

Tags: java, groovy, eval

Consider this, the value of

```
$RespNode
```

is

```
RespJson.seatbid[0].bid[0].price
```

I am trying to run

```
Eval.me('RespJson', RespJson, "assert $RespNode.toString() == '$aValue'")
```

but getting error

```
 [No such property: toString for class: java.lang.String]
```

When I run this (directly, Without Eval() )

```
assert RespJson.seatbid[0].bid[0].price.toString()==aValue
```

it runs fine (no error)

The below also works fine (without toString() )

```
   Eval.me('RespJson', RespJson, "assert $RespNode == '$aValue'")
```

any ideas , how to run `toString()` with `Eval()`  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method call in a GString needs curly brackets, otherwise the parents don't get parsed as part of the call:

```
class Foo {
  def getBar() { 'get bar' }
  def bar() { 'method bar' }
}

foo = new Foo()

assert "$foo.bar()".toString() == "get bar()"
assert "${foo.bar()}".toString() == "method bar"
```

Comment: Thank you. With curly brackets it worked fine. `Eval.me('RespJson', RespJson, "assert ${RespNode}.toString() == '$aValue'")`. But how do we know we've to use Gstring `${RespNode}` instead of `$RespNode` ?

Comment: @user1207289 `$RespNode` ist perfectly fine!  unless you go further down into something, that can be evaluated. e.g. `"It's $time o'clock"` is ok.  But `"Hello $world.My name is X"` most likely not.  It is good practice to use `${}` to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 2):

`$RespNode.toString()` will be replaced at once. You have to use `${RespNode}.toString()` to have it run via the eval.  Otherwise see @WillP's answer (`respNode.toString` is evaluated at once and toString is no property)

```
def respJson = [seatbid:[[bid:[[price:666.0G]]]]]
def respNode = 'respJson.seatbid[0].bid[0].price'
def aValue = '666.0'
Eval.me('respJson', respJson, "assert ${respNode}.toString() == '$aValue'")
```